# near "@gmail" Syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, authentication, logcat

I am creating login activity with Boolean function but get error while match email address with email address in database but give error.

This is my `dbHandler` class method:

```
 public Boolean loginCheck(String email,String password)
{
    Boolean flag=false;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email=" + email +" AND pass="+password;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 1){
      flag=true;
    }
    else
    {
      flag=false;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

this is java file code

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String emailValue=edtEmail.getText().toString();//this is EditText
            String passValue=edtPass.getText().toString();

            if(db.loginCheck(emailValue, passValue))
            {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(in);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", 2000).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username and Password not match", 5000).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

get error

```
 01-23 04:58:30.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@gmail": syntax error (code  1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM login WHERE email=stackoverflow@gmail.com AND pass=stackoverflow
 01-23 04:58:30.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  01-23 04:58:30.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2422):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
```

please provide Solution of it

Comment: You need to escape your parameters. Use `query` instead of `rawQuery` and pass te `email` parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is you are not passing the Strings in single quotes.

Better to use `rawQuery` with arguments' String array as:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "select * from "+TABLE_NAME +" where email = ? and pass = ? ", new String[]{email, password});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your @gmail in the quotes as-
"/'gmail/'"

```
tring selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE email=\'"
+ email+"\'" +" AND pass=\'"+password+"\'";
```

You need to put your strings in the quotes .